# 3D Convex Hulls CGAL::halfspace_intersection_3 with exact_constructions kernel

Tags: c++, cgal

I'd want to use the CGAL Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel with the 3D Convex Hulls function CGAL::halfspace_intersection_3 (CGAL Vers. 4.6.1), this is my simple test:

```js
#include "CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h"
#include "CGAL/Convex_hull_3/dual/halfspace_intersection_3.h"

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel  K;
typedef K::Plane_3                                         Plane;
typedef K::Point_3                                         Point;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<K>                              Polyhedron_3;

int main (void) {

    std::list<Plane> planes;
    Polyhedron_3 P;

    CGAL::halfspace_intersection_3(planes.begin(),
                                   planes.end(),
                                   P,
                                   boost::make_optional(Point(0, 0, 0)) );

    return 0;
}
```

but I get this error on compilation:

```
In file included from /CGAL-4.6.1/include/CGAL/Convex_hull_3/dual/halfspace_intersection_3.h:27:0,
                 from /test/halfspace_intersection_3.cpp:2:
/CGAL-4.6.1/include/CGAL/Convex_hull_3/dual/Convex_hull_traits_dual_3.h: In instantiation of ‘class CGAL::Convex_hull_3::Convex_hull_filtered_traits_dual_3<CGAL::Epeck>’:
/CGAL-4.6.1/include/CGAL/Convex_hull_3/dual/Convex_hull_traits_dual_3.h:266:15:   required from ‘class CGAL::Convex_hull_3::Convex_hull_traits_dual_3<CGAL::Epeck, true>’
/CGAL-4.6.1/include/CGAL/Convex_hull_3/dual/halfspace_intersection_3.h:259:32:   required from ‘void CGAL::halfspace_intersection_3(PlaneIterator, PlaneIterator, Polyhedron&, const boost::optional<typename Polyhedron::Vertex::Point_3>&) [with PlaneIterator = std::_List_iterator<CGAL::Plane_3<CGAL::Epeck> >; Polyhedron = CGAL::Polyhedron_3<CGAL::Epeck>; typename Polyhedron::Vertex::Point_3 = CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epeck>]’
/test/halfspace_intersection_3.cpp:18:73:   required from here
/CGAL-4.6.1/include/CGAL/Convex_hull_3/dual/Convex_hull_traits_dual_3.h:193:21: error: no type named ‘Exact_kernel_rt’ in ‘class CGAL::Epeck’
                     Exact_traits;
                     ^
/CGAL-4.6.1/include/CGAL/Convex_hull_3/dual/Convex_hull_traits_dual_3.h:201:21: error: no type named ‘Exact_kernel_rt’ in ‘class CGAL::Epeck’
                     Converter_exact_dual;
                     ^
/CGAL-4.6.1/include/CGAL/Convex_hull_3/dual/Convex_hull_traits_dual_3.h:210:45: error: no type named ‘Exact_kernel_rt’ in ‘class CGAL::Epeck’
                     Converter_approx_dual > Equal_3;
                                             ^
/CGAL-4.6.1/include/CGAL/Convex_hull_3/dual/Convex_hull_traits_dual_3.h:216:45: error: no type named ‘Exact_kernel_rt’ in ‘class CGAL::Epeck’
                     Converter_approx_dual > Collinear_3;
                                             ^
/CGAL-4.6.1/include/CGAL/Convex_hull_3/dual/Convex_hull_traits_dual_3.h:222:45: error: no type named ‘Exact_kernel_rt’ in ‘class CGAL::Epeck’
                     Converter_approx_dual > Coplanar_3;
                                             ^
/CGAL-4.6.1/include/CGAL/Convex_hull_3/dual/Convex_hull_traits_dual_3.h:228:45: error: no type named ‘Exact_kernel_rt’ in ‘class CGAL::Epeck’
                     Converter_approx_dual > Less_distance_to_point_3;
                                             ^
/CGAL-4.6.1/include/CGAL/Convex_hull_3/dual/Convex_hull_traits_dual_3.h:234:45: error: no type named ‘Exact_kernel_rt’ in ‘class CGAL::Epeck’
                     Converter_approx_dual > Has_on_positive_side_3;
                                             ^
/CGAL-4.6.1/include/CGAL/Convex_hull_3/dual/Convex_hull_traits_dual_3.h:240:45: error: no type named ‘Exact_kernel_rt’ in ‘class CGAL::Epeck’
                     Converter_approx_dual > Less_signed_distance_to_plane_3;
                                             ^
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/TestCGAL.dir/halfspace_intersection_3.cpp.o] Error 1
```

Is it possible to use the exact constructions kernel with 3D Convex Hulls CGAL::halfspace_intersection_3 ? Please could give me a clue about this? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed a bug in this version of CGAL. The fix is in [this commit](https://github.com/sloriot/cgal/commit/f3f73d10a129d065ee94d13b9eff14851a74ae5a).

Note that since you want to use a kernel with exact constructions, you better use [`CGAL::halfspace_intersection_with_constructions_3`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Convex_hull_3/group__PkgConvexHull3Functions.html#ga5c2ab0e6e63557e65ad7f2bdc3c351fc) which should be faster.